# How to attribute intersection points between poly and lineseg to poly

Tags: matlab, line-intersection, line-segment

I'm trying to plot an animal's trajectory from a set of coordinates as a line segment. I want to see how many coordinates are plotted inside a circular zone vs outside. I think that coordinates which intersect with the circle are being counted as both inside and outside, but I would like them to be strictly counted as inside. This is what I have so far:

```
[in,out] = intersect(circle_poly,trajectory);
plot(circle_poly)
hold on
plot(in(:,1),in(:,2),'b',out(:,1),out(:,2),'r')
legend('Polygon','Inside','Outside','Location','NorthWest')

num_frames_in = numel([in]) %count num elements/frames in polygon
num_frames_out = numel([out]) %count num element/frames outside polygon
total_frames = num_frames_in + num_frames_out
```

Any help would be really appreciated since I'm new to Matlab!

[image]

Comment: You can use function inpolygon. This will give you points lying on and in the polygon.

Comment: @SivaSrinivasKolukula Thank you!! I've figured it out!